# Create a ROI poligon: "Warning: Point outside band set or band set not defined".-Sentinel 2

Tags: qgis, band

[image: create raster of band]

I'm working on an assignment for college (geodesy), a data classification lab exercise. I downloaded and clipped the Sentinel bands to the area of ​​my municipality via clip raster bands in CSP, then I created a stack raster for band B 02, and I'm not sure but I think I assigned them the appropriate wavelengths, they didn't show me how in class I do. The problem is that when I want to start training data, I get the following error "Warning: Point outside band set or band set not defined". The layers are not in the same projection (Balkan zone 6 for layer "Dobroj", and "WGS 84 UTM Zone 33N" for raster layer calld "jetpack" who have bands). I have not received any instructions.

[image: projection]]
[image: projection2]

Comment: One of the mistakes is probably that I can't match the projections, because they don't match in the same projection, and I'm sure they refer to the same geographical location.In that case, how should I harmonize the cartographic projections

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please do not comment on your own post ([Edit] the post instead). Greetings and statements of urgency are not permitted. Your Question does not contain a question, making it difficult to answer. Managing spatial references is the first thing you should have been taught. The good news is that this is a very common problem (in fact, the most frequently asked one here). The bad news is that solving it isn't something we can do for you. I can say that defining a new CRS for a dataset is likely a mistake. If you did that, start over again.